# What kind of front end should I use?

Tags: web-apps, cloud-service, sql

I'm an intern at an electric company and I've been tasked with producing a front end web app with display and input capabilities. What they want to be able to do is put something like this [image: Imgur]  into a database. I will be given any resources I need and have prior experience in HTML and Java.

So far I've looked at things such as ASP.NET with visual studio and this just seems a little too much for me, being that I've only experienced Java and HTML.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Please edit your title to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

## Vaadin

If you already know Java, then the obvious choice is the [Vaadin Framework](http://www.Vaadin.com/framework).

Vaadin lets you rapidly develop a web app user-interface using only pure Java. Your app lives on the server-side, where you specify fields, labels, buttons, data grids, and other widgets arranged in layouts using only Java code.

At runtime, Vaadin generates the necessary HTML, CSS, DOM, and JavaScript to render remotely in the user’s web browser. As the user types in fields, clicks buttons, and so on, your server-side Java code is automatically invoked to respond.

So you can build professional-looking business apps that run quickly, reliably, and securely without having to learn that alphabet-soup of web technologies: HTML, CSS, DOM, JavaScript, AJAX, WebSocket, Push, etc. Vaadin uses all those standard web technologies, but does so on your behalf, behind the scene.

Vaadin is free-of-cost and open-source. In addition, the company Vaadin Ltd does sell a [spreadsheet add-on](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-spreadsheet) if you need it. But the built-in powerful and flexible [*Grid*](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid) widget may suffice from what I can seen in that screenshot you posted.

For a database, you can use anything with a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver). You might want to use the [*H2 Database Engine*](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). It is built in pure Java, and is free-of-cost, open-source, and actively developed. But if you need heavy-duty enterprise-level performance, features, and reliability, then [*Postgres*](https://www.postgresql.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably look for a PHP CRUD framework like http://xcrud.com/ or https://phpgrid.com/php-crud/

[image]

or write your own as it's not as difficult as it seems if you are familiar with PHP.